# how to publish web services and database

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse, web-services

**..I creat database mysql and web service by eclipse and android app and I publish  it on tomcat 7 on local network.
  I need to know if it can be  publish my database and web service over the internet.
 i.e( I need my android app access tha database and webservic online) .

i am using tomcat 7
android 2.3.3
eclipse juno**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what "publish over the internet" means.  I'm guessing that you want to deploy your web service on a server where it's visible on the internet, and you want to give that service access to a MySQL database in a secure way but not let unwanted users get at it.

You could try [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/) for a low-cost start on this.  You'll just pay for what you use that way.  Set up an EC account with them and install Tomcat and MySQL.